# Changing package name of app utilizing Facebook Audience Network

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-audience-network, package-name

Our app utilizes Facebook Audience Network ads on Android. It's published on the Google play store for some time now.

Due to circumstances beyond our control, it seems that we'll have to change the app's package name and re-list it on the Google play store as a new app.

We aim to keep the current app id on Facebook to maintain user's identities, users' permission approval, login, server integration, ad manager accounts and also ad placement data.

Is this possible? How should we prepare for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. It was easier than expected but we did stumble upon an interesting GOTCHA.

**Keeping the Facebook app id**

Once we've changed the package name and re-published the app, all we had to do was to go to the developer portal, and on the Settings tab, under Android, enter the new package name.

**Keeping the Audience Network ads running**

All was fine and dandy, then a week after the switch we've stopped receiving ads from Audience Network. It seems that Audience Network maintains a seperate list of apps and package names.

So back to the developer dashboard. This time, under the Audience Network tab, in Apps, we've had to add our new app. Once approved everything was fine again.